# Why does this chaining of functions compile?

Tags: scala

From http://backchatio.github.io/hookup/scaladoc/io/backchat/hookup/DefaultHookupClient.html have this code :

```
  new DefaultHookupClient(HookupClientConfig(new URI("ws://localhost:8080/thesocket"))) {

    def receive = {
      case Disconnected(_) ⇒ println("The websocket to " + uri.toASCIIString + " disconnected.")
      case TextMessage(message) ⇒ {
        println("RECV: " + message)
        send("ECHO: " + message)
      }
    }

    connect() onSuccess {
      case Success ⇒
        println("The websocket is connected.")
      case _ ⇒
    }
  }
```

in client.scala (https://github.com/backchatio/hookup/blob/2913794eb45d90d65713c9fd631b427abcca2d05/src/main/scala/io/backchat/hookup/client.scala) `connect` is defined as :

```
def connect(protocols: String*): Future[OperationResult] = synchronized {
…   
257           delay {
258             connect(wireFormat.get.name)
259           }
260       }
261     }
```

OperationResult is defined as (https://github.com/backchatio/hookup/blob/2913794eb45d90d65713c9fd631b427abcca2d05/src/main/scala/io/backchat/hookup/operation_result.scala) :

```
sealed trait OperationResult {
11    /**
12     * Flag for the java api to indicate success
…   
30    def children: java.util.List[OperationResult] = List[OperationResult]().asJava
31  }
```

Within chained methods `connect() onSuccess {` the `connect()` method appears to block until `onSuccess` is invoked ? Within the source of https://github.com/backchatio/hookup/ onSuccess does not appear to be defined so how does this method chain compile ?

I would expect `onSuccess` to be defined within an abstract class similar to :

```
abstract class DefaultHookupClient {

  def onSuccess(): Unit

}
```

Comment: What happens if you open the code in an IDE and follow the definition?

Comment: @Augusto I'm not using an IDE, but to check the type I should be able to use something like  ?: 'def checkType : String = connect() onSuccess {' and compiler will complain with expected type for 'connect() onSuccess' , this is what your asking for, type of 'connect() onSuccess' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [latest doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0-M4/scala/concurrent/Future.html) is more clear about the execution semantics.

```
Since this method executes asynchronously...
```

Not sure why you think it blocks. That would be evil.

Note that `onSuccess` is deprecated in 2.12. Use `onComplete` instead, handling all cases, which is the same idea: "Run a side-effect when the future completes. Don't bother telling me, I don't even care."

Answer (score 1):

Please install and use an IDE... scala is a PITA without an IDE, well very often even without an IDE too.

The method `onSuccess` is defined in the [Future trait in scala.concurent](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future).

Again, get an IDE. Otherwise you're for into a really, really frustraiting journey.

Comment: what is the PITA acronym ? 'well very often even without an IDE too.' should read 'well very often even with an IDE too.'

Comment: PITA= pain in the ass. It's scala 2nd name :D

Comment: ha, I see. btw I omitted the ? , 'well very often even without an IDE too.' should read 'well very often even with an IDE too. ?'